# Geopandas to_crs flips map

Tags: geopandas, pyproj

I have a shape file over Swedish historical municipalities. The CRS is epsg:3034 according to the documentation.

Geopandas to_crs flips the map when converting the coordinate system to WGS84.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

[Code from jupyter notebook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmCcM.jpg)

Comment: Did you mean to use `epsg:4326` instead of `epsg:4328` ?

Comment: Yes, of course. That was silly. Thanks a lot!